# Find the equation to the locus of the middle point of the chord of the circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ for the given data.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Find the equation to the locus of the middle point of the chord of the circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ which subtends right angle at a given point $(a,b)$

[image]
My attempt is as follows:-

Equation of chord passing through the midpoint $(h,k)$

$$xh+yk+g(x+h)+k(y+f)+c=h^2+k^2+2hg+2fk+c$$
$$x(h+g)+y(k+f)=h^2+k^2+hg+fk$$

$$x=\dfrac{-y(k+f)+h^2+k^2+hg+fk}{h+g}\tag{1}$$

Now we if we place $x$ in the equation of circle to find endpoints of chord, equation will become very huge, so how to proceed from here?

Comment: It has to be complicated. If $(a,b)$ is close enough to the circle, you might have up to 4 intersection points with two perpendicular lines through $(a,b)$, two on each line. That means that you have 4 chords for the same orientation of the perpendicular lines. If $(a,b)$ is far enough from the circle, you have no chords obeying your angle constraint.

Comment: Solve it for $f = g = b = 0$ and a radius of $1$ first. Then use rescaling, rotation, and translation to recover the general case.